# How to make use of the information the user added in a list from DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, linq

With datacontext from the main grid, I'm trying to use the collected information from the user and store it in a list and then later use that list and be able to get the information with LINQ.

ColDiv._inventaire.Add(inventaire);

Coldiv is one of my cs files and _inventaire is the list and inventaire is the data from the datacontext.

The code of ColDiv is inside one of my class :

```cs
class CollectionsDiverses
{
    public List<Client> _client = new List<Client>();
    public List<Inventaire> _inventaire = new List<Inventaire>();
    public List<Vente> _VenteArticle = new List<Vente>();
```

Here is the code to put the datacontext from the grid in the propreties and inside the list. (Lists belows)

```cs
Inventaire inventaire = null;
frmArticle frmArticle = new frmArticle

bool? bReturn = frmArticle.ShowDialog();
if (bReturn == true)
{
    inventaire = (Inventaire)frmArticle.grdMain.DataContext;
    inventaire.Créé = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    ColDiv._inventaire.Add(inventaire);
    dgInventaire.Items.Refresh()
}
```

Now logically, it's stored. Now, From another from, a TextBox with the TextChanged event, catching the ID of a (for example) client :

```cs
private void TxtNoArticle_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _venteEdition.NoArticle = Int32.Parse(txtNoArticle.Text); 
        _venteEdition.ArticleComplet = ArticleCompletToString(_venteEdition.NoArticle);
        lblArticleComplet.Content = _venteEdition.ArticleComplet;
    }
    catch (Exception){}
```

Then proceed with LINQ from a method to find the client with the ID the user entered:

```cs
public string ArticleCompletToString(int iNombre)
{
    string sArticle = "";

    var req = from art in ColDiv._inventaire
              where art.No == iNombre // art.No is the ID the user wants and iNombre is the ID the user entered in the TextBox
              select new
              {
                  art.Modèle,
                  art.Marque
              };
    foreach (var i in req)
    {
        sArticle = i.Modèle + " " + i.Marque;
    }
    return sArticle;
```

It's supposed to return exactly the informations I want from the list but it looks like it doesn't even create a new Inventaire.

Comment: How do you define `ColDiv` and `_ColDiv`...? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify your question accordingly.

Comment: They are the same

Comment: So how do you initialize `ColDiv`?

Comment: I initialize right below public partial class MinaWindow : Window ... I initialize it like that : private CollectionsDiverses ColDiv = new CollectionsDiverses();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok found the issues. I was initializing ColDiv three times in three different forms
So the only thing you have to do is to make your initialization in the main and make it public and static. In the other form to intialize it simply do as follow :

```cs
public partial class frmVentes : Window
{
    private CollectionsDiverses _ColDiv;

    public frmVentes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._ColDiv = MainWindow.ColDiv;
    }

//...
```

In your main code, it looks like this :

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static CollectionDiverses ColDiv = new CollectionsDiverses();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
//...
```

Now in your CollectionsDiverses class you want to change it to public like this

```cs
public class CollectionsDiverses
{
//...
```

You will have to create an internal proprety for your list :

```cs
private List<Client> client = new List<Client>();
private List<Inventaire> inventaire = new List<Inventaire>();
//...

internal List<Client> Client { get => client; set => client = value; }
internal List<Vente> VenteArticle { get => venteArticle; set => venteArticle = value; }
//...
```

That's it ! It's now fixed, and I can use the information between different forms!